# Applications of Jensen's Formula to entire functions of finite order

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

I am trying to understand a frequently omitted technical detail in applications of Jensen's Formula to bound the number of zeros of entire functions of finite order.

We say that an entire function $f(s)$ is of order $\lambda$ if $\lambda$ it the greatest lower bound of all $a$ such that
$$ \lvert f(z) \rvert = O\big( \exp(\lvert z \rvert^a) \big).$$
Jensen's Formula is the following.

> **Jensen's Formula**
>
> If $f$ is an entire function insize $\lvert z \rvert \leq R$ such that $f(0) \neq 0$ and $f(z) \neq 0$ on $\lvert z \rvert = R$, then
> $$ \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \log \lvert f (Re^{i \theta}) \rvert d \theta
> = \log \lvert f(0) \rvert + \int_0^R \frac{n(r)}{r} dr,$$
> where $n(r)$ is the number of zeros of $f$ of absolute value less than $r$.

A classical application of Jensen's Formula is to bound the number of zeros of entire functions of finite order. The argument goes like this. Let $f$ be an entire function of order $\lambda$ and let $n(\cdot)$ count the number of zeros of this $f$. Then
$$ n(R) \log 2 \leq \int_R^{2R} \frac{n(r)}{r} dr, $$
so that
$$n(R) \log 2 \leq \int_0^{2R} \frac{n(r)}{r} dr
= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \log \lvert f (Re^{i \theta}) \rvert d\theta - \log \lvert f(0) \rvert.
$$
Since $f$ is of order $\lambda$, for any $\alpha > \lambda$ we have that this integral is bounded above by
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \log \lvert f (Re^{i \theta}) \rvert d\theta \ll \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} R^{\alpha} d \theta = R^\alpha, \tag{1}$$
and thus
$$ n(R) = O(R^{\alpha}) $$
for any $\alpha > \lambda$.

> My question is about the bound $(1)$. It's true that $f(Re^{i \theta}) \ll \exp(R^\alpha)$, and thus for large values of $f(Re^{i \theta})$, we have that $\log \lvert f(Re^{i\theta}) \rvert \ll R^\alpha$. But what about cases when $f(Re^{i \theta})$ is very near to $0$? How can we get away without producing lower bounds for $\lvert f(Re^{i \theta}) \rvert$ to remove the possibility that $\log \lvert f(Re^{i \theta}) \rvert$ isn't particularly large because $f (Re^{i \theta})$ is small?

One attempt at a fix would be to specify any $\epsilon > 0$ and choose only $R$ such that the circle $\lvert z \rvert = R$ remains at most $\epsilon$ away from any zero. But this isn't always possible. For example, the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ essentially become dense on the critical line.

I think if I understood this proof for the classical case of the Riemann zeta function, then I would understand it more generally. But in the books of Ivic and Titchmarsh on the zeta function, they don't acknowledge any additional attention to be given to the possibility that $\log \lvert \xi(s) \rvert$ might be large because $\xi(s)$ is very small. In Montgomery's book *Multiplicative Number Theory*, chapter 11, there is simply the (incorrect) statement that $\log \lvert f(Re^{i\theta})\rvert < R^\alpha$ for all sufficiently large $R$. This makes me suspect that there is some simple resolution that I don't currently see.

Comment: Note that the integral of $\log |f(Re^{i\theta})|$ increases with $R$ by subharmonicity so only upper bounds are needed; you can as well take $\log^+$ instead

Comment: Ah, this was exactly the observation that I needed. Thank you. (And in fact I now realize I was conflating $\lvert \log f \rvert$ with $\log \lvert f \rvert$, or perhaps I was thinking in complex terms so that all infinities are $\infty$, even though $\log \lvert f \rvert$ is real-valued and thus there is a difference between $-\infty$ and $\infty$... I'm not sure which, as now things snapped into place).

Comment: The case you mention, where $\log |f(z)|$ large negative is worrying, happens in the Weierstrass factorization theorem, and there is a theorem to bound the negative values in term of the positive values (when $\log f$ is entire ie. after removing the zeros whose upper density is given from your question)